# Should I build the Kitchen Island on top of tile or remove?

Tags: kitchens, island

I am rebuilding my kitchen island it has a half wall already installed which is secured to the concrete floor.  I want to extend the wall and make the island bigger.  To do that the wall will extend over existing tile.  Is it OK to drill holes through the grout and fasten the wall extension to the concrete.  The wall would be on top of the ceramic tile or would it be better to cut out the tile a space big enough to put the wood wall directly to the concrete subfloor.

I have seen it done both ways but which is the best and most correct way to build it?

Comment: Are you asking about the wall or the cabinet? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way your other cabinets are done so everything is the same height.

Also removing the tile is a little bit tougher than you think.  You can probably do it with an angle grinder but you risk the tile chipping badly or cracking.  Going this route will also require molding over base plate to cover flaws.  (and I almost forgot, when I have removed tile in past for things like this it was a PITA sometimes to actually make the area flat.)